# Could not find settings panel "unity-appearance"

Tags: unity, 13.04

I just updated/upgraded (technically dist-upgrade but it was already 13.04) this morning and now my appearance setting is missing. I can select it from the unity menu but nothing happens and it's missing from the settings options. Any ideas how to get it back? I have gnome-control-center-unity installed and the other thing that has happened is that the background for the other settings has turned black. Here are the relevant entries in /var/log/dist-upgrade/ [apt.log](http://pastebin.com/4nN471m5), [apt-term.log](http://pastebin.com/qveiVjBF) and I'm actually not seeing anything in main.log relevant to this - it's all from 5/3/13 instead of today. I'm not entirely sure what other logs could/would be helpful and I'm not sure if this is in fact a bug or if I just screwed something up.

Some other things I've tried:

- purge and re-install gnome-control-center-unity
- rm -rf ~/.config/* (a little overkill but I was getting frustrated)
- purging/removing gnome-shell

Admittedly it's not a requirement to have the appearance settings back but it would make my life a bit more pleasant -I could just install nitrogen or something for wallpaper management but I do enjoy the auto-hide of my old unity set-up for my dual monitors.

Comment: I was running on this trouble also, if you had found the solution please answer it also by yourself. Meanwhile I'll keep searching on it. Thank so much

Answer (score -2):

You may just try
re-install gnome-control-center
without -unity